# What is nodePipe.sock file and is it safe to remove it?

Tags: macos

I found files named `nodePipe*.sock` in my home directory. Can I remove them safely?

```
~ ll | grep sock
srwxr-xr-x    1 myself  staff     0B  8 26 17:20 nodePipe32098.sock
srwxr-xr-x    1 myself  staff     0B  8 26 19:30 nodePipe33098.sock
srwxr-xr-x    1 myself  staff     0B  9  4 11:08 nodePipe5150.sock
srwxr-xr-x    1 myself  staff     0B  8 24 14:51 nodePipe6158.sock
srwxr-xr-x    1 myself  staff     0B  8 30 19:16 nodePipe64976.sock
srwxr-xr-x    1 myself  staff     0B  8 27 12:22 nodePipe9262.sock
srwxr-xr-x    1 myself  staff     0B  9  4 12:10 nodePipe9284.sock
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe to remove it.

I encountered the same problem and did a little research. I believe this is somehow related to the problem described in this [page](https://github.com/cytle/wechat_web_devtools/blob/master/package.nw/node_modules/node-sync-ipc/README.md#sock-file).

Your username suggests that you are a Chinese developer as I am, and it is very likely that you used the `wechatdevtools` (offered by the Chinese tech company Tencent) to develop WeChat mini-programs.

Turns out the problem is probably caused by using the `wechatwebdevtools` app on linux/macOS and debugging a WeChat mini-program. Every time the node module is run by the `wechatwebdevtools`, it creates a `nodePipe${parentPid}.sock` file in the Unix home directory. In most cases, these files should be deleted automatically, but not always.

Hence I believe it is safe to manually delete these files.